# XPath expression to get a string after a <br> tag

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get the content in `article/div/p` but only the date after the `<br>` tag. How is that done?

```
<article>
    <h2>Man rescued after falling into Crater Lake</h2>
    <p class="summary highlight">
        Man rescued after falling 800 feet into Crater Lake in Oregon
    </p>

    <div class="body">
       <p>by Joe Sutton<br>
            June 11, 2019
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

```php
$expression = "article/div/p";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//br/following-sibling::text()
```

will select all following sibling text nodes after `br`.